# run applications from external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, imac, external-disk

I have a hard drive taken from an old macbook.
I am working on a university iMac, I want to run applications such as Android Studio from the External Hard drive however when I run the application from the external drive, the machine loads the Android studio application on the iMac not the External version. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

To open the app from an external disk, you have to refer to it explicitly using a Terminal command:

`open /Volumes/<volume_name_of_external_disk>/<path_to_application>/Android\ Studio.app`

Having never used Android Studio, I don't know if there is a space between 'Android' and 'Studio' in the app name. If there is, the back-slash character in the `open` command is required to delimit the space character.

Ex: `open /Volumes/ExternalDisk/Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Comment: ok thanks I will try this when I'm next in the lab